# Label text with a horizontal curly bracket

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm displaying sentences and some phrases are from a certain class. Now, I want to include these phrases' classes with a curly bracket right above, as shown in the attached mockup.

[image: Text fragments are labeled via horizontal curly brackets]

My question is: What is the best way to implement such a functionality? Are there any code examples?

EDIT (current code added):

**HTML**

```
<token>Effects</token>
<token>of</token>
<token>an</token>
<token>ascorbic</token>
<elem type="drug">
    <token>acid-derivative</token>
    <token>dentifrice</token>
</elem>
<token>in</token>
<elem type="person">
    <token>patients</token>
</elem>
<token>with</token>
<elem type="disease">
    <token>gingivitis</token>
</elem>
```

**CSS**

```
token {
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

**Fiddle demo of the code**

https://jsfiddle.net/ab0L55v1/

Comment: Do you have any code doing any of the mockup you're showing?

Comment: I don't have a full solution, but I'd start with making the key phrases/words separate `span`s: `<p>Effects of an ascorbic <span class="drug">acid-derivative dentifrice</span><span class="person">...</span>...</p>`. Then you could address those via CSS (possibly pseudo-selectors like `:before` and `:after`), as well as with JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that's all done with CSS and pseudo-elements (and an additional HTML element for the labeling). It should be self-explanatory, but if you have questions about it, just ask...

```css
.container1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 3px 8px 0 0;
}

token {
  margin-left: 6px;
}

elem[type="drug"],
elem[type="person"],
elem[type="disease"] {
  position: relative;
}

elem[type="drug"]::after,
elem[type="person"]::after,
elem[type="disease"]::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  left: 3%;
  width: 94%;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3em;
  left: 3%;
  width: 94%;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
}

.label:after {
  content: "|";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2em;
  left: 3%;
  width: 94%;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
}

.drug {
  color: red;
}

.person {
  color: blue;
}

.disease {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <token>Effects</token>
  <token>of</token>
  <token>an</token>
  <token>ascorbic</token>
  <elem type="drug">
    <token>acid-derivative</token>
    <token>dentifrice</token>
    <div class=" label drug">
      Drug
    </div>
  </elem>
  <token>in</token>
  <elem type="person">
    <token>patients</token>
    <div class=" label person">
      Person
    </div>
  </elem>
  <token>with</token>
  <elem type="disease">
    <token>gingivitis</token>
    <div class=" label disease">
      Disease
    </div>
  </elem>

</div>
```

Comment: Just did some testing with your code. Everything works as intended. The only thing I've added is `white-space: nowrap;` to `elem` in the CSS to prevent line breaks for multi word elements.

Answer (score 2):

This is not *easily* achieved with HTML and CSS. For advanced formatting, I had good results with [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/), which allows LaTeX-like formatting.

For example, the format

```latex
$\overbrace{\text{Big ones, small ones}}^{Coconuts}\text{, some as big as your head}$
```

Will look like:

[image]

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/AqDCA/940/
See also: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/547)
[jqMath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) is a lightweight alternative, with fewer features and a smaller footprint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Kobi. Looks great. It does not matter if it is not a pure css+html solution, I'll check your proposed solution now.

Comment: I had some problems including the html elements, i.e. the "<token>" elements. Therefore, I went with Johannes' solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A *simple* option, though less stylish is to use [`<ruby>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby) tags. Note that these are meant for East Asian characters, and might have odd formatting with English text:

```css
ruby rt {font-size:12px;}
ruby {color:#4a4;}
ruby.drug {color:#44a;}
```

```html
Maybe this can <ruby class="drug">be done<rt>Drug</ruby> with <ruby>HTML<rt>Han</ruby>.
```