# CSS Flexbox - How to align one item on top of text, always following the text?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

How can the number always be positioned over the text but always following that text? Whatever I do it doesnt happen as the number is never right after the text.Thank you!!

```
<div style="display: flex, flexDirection: column">
<badge/>
<p>{title}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I once answered a remotely similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42648096/5641669 Maybe the approach used in that answer can help you...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: flex, flexDirection:row; align-items:center; ">
<badge/>
<p>{title}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answer, and explain how your solution solve the problem.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.